# Cannot find type System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256 on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, encryption, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, sha

I'want to use SHA 256 encryption on windows phone 8.1 c# xaml.
But i am getting the following error:
Cannot find type System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm in module mscorlib.dll

And indeed System.Security.Cryptography is not available on Windows Phone (or windows 8 store).
Windows.Security.Cryptography however is available, but I couldn't find this class there as well.

What i need to use SHA 256 encryption ? Is thereany dll for that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit more difficult if you're doing Universal App.  But to get you started

```
using Windows.Security.Cryptography;
using Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core;

HashAlgorithmProvider hap = HashAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(HashAlgorithmNames.Sha256);   
CryptographicHash ch = hap.CreateHash();            

// read in bytes from file then append with ch.Append(data)           

Windows.Storage.Streams.IBuffer b_hash = ch.GetValueAndReset();       // hash it
string hash_string = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToHexString(b_hash);   // encode it to a hex string for easy reading
```

---

You have to create a HashAlgorithmProvider and provided it with the HashAlgorithm you want to use

see `HashAlgorithmNames.` namespace for all supported Hashes

Then you create a `CryptographicHash` from the above.

Then you add in bytes into the `CryptographicHash` using `.Append(data)`

Then you compute the hash.

Then you can encode it to a hex string if you like.

---

Shameless Screenshot of my Hashing App :)

[Click Here for Fullsize Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvXWA.png)
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time for answering my question. So i can use the  help of this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.security.cryptography.core.hashalgorithmprovider.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1 right?

Comment: @asitis Yeah, that looks correct.  you can basically copy my code if you like, you just have to fill in the buffer.  I did that way so I can hash huge files 2GB+ easily.